# Crystax NDK linker error

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk, linker

I'm trying to get working [Crystax NDK example](https://www.crystax.net/en/blog/2) and have **the following error** (I've made up `PATH/TO/MY/CRYSTAXNDK/` of course):

```
$ ndk-build APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a
[armeabi-v7a] Executable     : test-boost
PATH/TO/MY/CRYSTAXNDK/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/sources/boost/1.59.0/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:88: error: undefined reference to 'boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Actually, this example is a bit outdated and I've already solved this error:

```
Android NDK: ERROR:PATH/TO/MY/CRYSTAXNDK/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/sources/boost/1.59.0/Android.mk:boost_atomic_static: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
Android NDK: Check that PATH/TO/MY/CRYSTAXNDK/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/sources/boost/1.59.0/libs/armeabi-v7a/gnu-/libboost_atomic.a exists  or that its path is correct
```

by adding `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9` into `Android.mk`. 
I've also replaced `$(call import-module,boost/1.57.0)` with `$(call import-module,boost/1.59.0)` to call actual version of Boost library.

So, my Android.mk looks as following:

```
# Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION = 4.9

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE           := test-boost
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := test.cpp gps.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := boost_serialization_static
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

$(call import-module,boost/1.59.0)
```

My crystax-ndk directory is in a system path. I understand that the cause of my problem is that NDK linker is unable to find proper Boost libraries. But I don't know how to configure it in such a way that it will automatically choose libraries depending on the target architecture. 
Please help me to figure out the configuration of the linker! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is [bug](https://tracker.crystax.net/issues/1233). Shortly speaking, libboost_serialization.so was built with GNU libstdc++ v5, but when you call `ndk-build`, it link final binary with GNU libstdc++ v4.9, which is binary incompatible with GNU libstdc++ v5 (specifically, std::basic_string; if interested, please look [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html) for details).

This is fixed by [a7c363377](https://github.com/crystax/android-platform-ndk/commit/a7c3633773f394958aed114a4fdf4350e98094d6) and will be included to the next bug-fix release (10.3.2). In the meantime, you can apply that patch manually on your crystax-ndk-10.3.1 file tree to solve the problem.

Comment: thank you for your fix! I don't fully understand yet how does the whole NDK work but shouldn't I rebuild boost libraries after applying this fix? 
If yes, could you point me to the documentation or say how should I do it? Because the error is still the same.

Comment: No, you shouldn't rebuild Boost libraries for that. CrystaX NDK already include prebuilt Boost libraries, which are built against all C++ Standard Library implementations - i.e. two GNU libstdc++ versions and two LLVM libc++ versions. The error goes from mismatch of C++ stdlib used when Boost libraries where built, and used to build your application. That fix make it the same.

However, if that doesn't help in your case, probably there is something else making C++ stdlib mismatch. I can't say what exactly, but if you'd provide minimal example reproducing the problem, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: What do you mean by **you can apply that patch manually on your crystax-ndk-10.3.1**? I am experiencing this error now, and it is troubling.  I've to copy the code from patch a7c363377, and still getting the same error!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem following the CrytaX blog tutorial. I fixed it by adding the following

```
# Application.mk
APP_ABI := all
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 5
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

The 2nd line fixed the ndk-build Boost gcc lib path error. The 3rd line fixed the "only position independent executables" problem when invoking the executable.